# htaccess Deny all except url

Tags: .htaccess

I use my website to host some files, but I do not want users to download the files directly. I first want to show a preview of the docx file (what I am doing via the officeviewer from Microsoft).
Since the viewer is an embed-link that has a parameter to the file, I obviously can't block the URL from Microsoft.

I have tried to allow it by IP, by URL and have been looking around on the internet, but I haven't found a solution yet that works for me. I mostly found solutions to block a site from viewing and I have no clue to make it inverse.

My code is currently this:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from view.officeapps.live.com
```

How can I keep denying all, but allowing the domain of view.officeapps.live.com?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code is for Apache 2.2. Are you sure your server is not running on 2.4? As if so that would no longer work.

Comment: Currently it is not working, besides, yes I am using Apache 2.4.

Comment: Check the documentation here. Shows you what to use for 2.4. [Upgrade for 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html)